# Flask: NameError: 'app' is not defined?

Tags: python, flask

My Flask application has been running fine for the last 24 hours, however I just took it offline to work on it and i'm trying to start it up again and i'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runserver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/MY NAME/APP FOLDER NAME/app.py", line 15, in <module>
    from Views import *
  File "/home/MY NAME/APP FOLDER NAME/Views.py", line 1, in <module>
    @app.route('/contact', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

I am running the application currently by calling `python runserver.py`

**runserver.py:**

```
from app import app

app.run(threaded = True, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

**Views.py**: contains all of my routes, I won't post them all, as the error is coming from the first time `app` is mentioned in this file.

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg = Message("CENSORED,
            sender='CENSORED',
            recipients=['CENSORED'])
        msg.body = """
            From: %s <%s>,
            %s
            """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
        mail.send(msg)
        return "><p><br>Successfully  sent message!</p></body>"
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

**app.py:** Here is the top of my app.py file, where I define `app = Flask(__name__)` as well as import my statements.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, send_file
from geopy.geocoders import Bing
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut
import re
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Style, Font
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from Helper_File import *
from Lists import *
from Views import *
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from forms import ContactForm

global today

geolocator = Bing('Censored')

app = Flask(__name__)
```

**EDIT: I have made the changes suggested in the answer below, but am getting this when I access the page:**

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Here is my file structure:

```
DHLSoftware.com
|-static
    |-style.css
|-templates
    |- seperate html file for each page template
|-app.py
|-forms.py
|-helper_file.py
|-Lists.py
|-runserver.py
|-Views.py
```

Comment: In `views.py` are you importing app?

Comment: @Adam Oh, I'm not doing that currently. Would that just be `from app import app`?

Comment: Believe so. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app.py` you should remove the `from Views import *`. Instead in your `Views.py` you need to have `from app import app`

That will bring app into the views namespace and I believe that should work for you.

Comment: I made those changes, and now the application is starting, but I am getting: `Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.` when I access the page.

Comment: Could this be caused by `app.py` not being able to find `views.py`? Because i'm not importing views anymore.

Comment: Was able to come to a conclusion. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Yeah sorry I did not get back to you on this. Hope you figured out the other error but what I posted should be the answer and thank you for marking it as so. Flask is great. Check out `Flask Web Development by Miguel Grinberg`. That is how I really learned Flask.